# Error con com.android.support:appcompat-v7:19.1.0 API 19

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Amigos estoy trabajando en una app de geolocalizacion, para un android v 4.4 y alli estoy usando appcompat-v7, pero me esta generando un error debido a que no esta bien configurado, ya he hecho unos cambios pero no me resulta, entonces acudo a ustedes para que me ayuden por favor, aqui el codigo:
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 19
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.academiaandroid.datosgps"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.13-rc-1'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:19.1.0'
}
```

y este es el error generado:

```
ERROR: Failed to resolve: com.android.support:appcompat-v7:19.1.0
Affected Modules: app
```

Answer (score 0):

Podría probar agregando el siguiente código en

> build.gradle(Module:app)

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven { url 'https://maven.google.com' }
    }
}
```

finalice sincronizando su proyecto.
Saludos.

Answer (score 0):

añadi el codigo y ahora me muestra solo esto:

```
ERROR: Failed to open zip file.
Gradle's dependency cache may be corrupt (this sometimes occurs after a network connection timeout.)
Re-download dependencies and sync project (requires network)
Re-download dependencies and sync project (requires network)
```

he tratado de descargar pero me sigue saliendo....

otra cosa mira este post:
[Android Studio keeps refusing to resolve com.android.support:appcompat-v7:29.0.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57022083/android-studio-keeps-refusing-to-resolve-com-android-supportappcompat-v729-0-1)

es un problema parecido al mio, pero alli usan una API 29, en mi caso es una API 19, mi intencion es correr la aplicacion en un celular con andoid 4.4

esta es la aplicacion que quiero correr:
[DatosGPS](https://academiaandroid.com/?ddownload=7595)

la consegui aqui:
[Geolocalización](https://academiaandroid.com/geolocalizacion-obtencion-coordenadas-desde-app-android/)

lo comparto contigo para ver si puedes ayudarme a que corra. gracias por tu atencion

Answer (score 0):

**Estas definiendo en tu proyecto un `compileSdkVersion 19` y `targetSdkVersion 23`, estas versiones son obsoletas**, incluso el uso de `compile` es obsoleto, debe usarse:

```
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:19.1.0'
```

de hecho necesitas actualizar a versión 26 como mínimo ya que esto es indicado por `Google`:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Actualiza Android Studio y define como mínimo :

`compileSdkVersion 26` y `targetSdkVersion 26`

Comment: pero si no le dan mas soportes a las versiones como la 4.4.2(API 19), por que android Studio me dejo descargar dicha API, eso fue el miercoles de la semana pasada..... no entiendo